# Command Line Copy or Delete

Tags: command-line, robocopy

I used robocopy to copy just pdf's from an external hard drive and place them on our server.

source destination *.pdf

It copied over all the folders and subfolders even if there wasn't a .pdf file in the folder. Can someone help me either....

a) Delete empty folders or b) Copy over only folders and subfolders that have .pdf's in them?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following command for copy over only folders and subfolders that have an extension in them in this case ".pdf"

```
ROBOCOPY sourcePath destPath *.pdf /MIR /S
```

This will only all files with that extensions and folders that have files with that extension and does not include empty folder.

Comment: Thank you Daniel Ballesteros. What does /MIR & /S do? Also, someone told me that /Z enables a restartable mode. Can I add that to your code? Does the order matter?

Comment: By trial and error, I figured out that /S mean non-empty folders. Thank you. What is /MIR?

Comment: Order does not matter.
The /MIR is equivalent to /E and /PURGE.

/E command: Include subdirectories.
/PURGE Command: Delete files and directories that no more exist in the oirigin.

Yes you can use the /Z command if you want to copy in a restartable mode.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this ROBOCOPY command for deleting empty folders:

```
ROBOCOPY myfolder myfolder /S /MOVE
```

Here source and destination both are 'myfolder'.

Comment: Thank you Arvindsinc2. I was able to clean up my empty folders.